# How to make bounce button animation in react-native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

If we use css, we can archive bounce button by

```
.order {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  text-align:center;
  opacity: 1;
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  -webkit-animation: bounce .3s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: bounce .3s infinite alternate;
  animation: bounce .3s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  to { -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  to { -moz-transform: scale(1.2); }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
```

But problem is, react-native, we can't use library like `web-kit`, so i wonder how can we make bounce animation for button, or bigger view, how to make animation in react native app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Spring is also supported in React Native. You should use React Spring for animation in React native. I have attached the bounce effect example. There are other effects also on website of React Spring like Pulse, Hover etc.

You should take a look at the React Spring Docs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pmndrs/react-spring/tree/master/demo/src/sandboxes/css-keyframes

Comment: Wow that lib look so coool, thank for your answer

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh Yeah for animation purposes I have always used React Spring.